# How do I group/un-group parent/child windows?

Tags: window-management

I was rummaging around in **gconf-editor** yesterday, and I noticed a setting to Group or Un-group a set of windows... (but I forget the exact Key-name)

This setting was something which looked like a swtich to the default behavioural difference between Ubuntu and Windows... It was called something like: Group windows/dialogs

I switched to "Group". This locks a child window/dialog to the parent, so that it appears "on-top" of the parent  (which is pretty much the MS-Windws standard).  I thought I'd try it out, to see which mode I preferred...

An typical example of the "Grouped" behaviour is: An Open-file dialog is forced to stay on top of its parent, until it is closed.

24 hours later, I've decided I prefer the default Ubuntu way... but I can't find that option again.

Does anyone know which/where it is?

Comment: Hmm... This is a hard one. There's a Compiz group plugin that has gconf settings, but it's behavior is different than what you're describing. If you really can't remember, your best bet might just be grepping through your settings for a key with a familiar name. Try something like: `gconftool-2  --recursive-list / |grep -C 3 "group"`

Comment: Hard?... damn elusive :)  I am currently installing Lucid in a VM and am about to do a diff on the --recursive-list outputs... I'm not familiar enough with Linux/Ubuntu yet to know a good diff program, so I'll probably just do a visual, at first... still working on it ...

Comment: `meld` is good differ. But you can try `diff` in bash also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question has been resolved in this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12845/clicking-a-windows-decoration-brings-the-window-to-the-top-but-clicking-elswher) ...

The transition from this question to the one I now refer you to, is explained in the comment I wrote to Martin's answer...

Answer (score 1):

The only known location for that sort of option is:

`/apps/gnome/interface`

Comment: I don't have a `/apps/gnome/interface` key... I do have `/desktop/gnome/interface`, but nothing in it seems relevant.., I now experience an odd window behaviour, but I may have mis-represented it here Amending this question would convolute it too much, so I have asked a new question which describes the behaviour more clearly... http://askubuntu.com/questions/12845/clicking-a-windows-decoration-brings-the-window-to-the-top-but-clicking-elswher ... I've gone through most of the keys, but can't find it!... I know I tweaked something, and I have the odd behaviour, so I assume these are releated.