# Which gconf-editor setting effects the "on-top" relationship of Parent/Child windows and dialogs?

Tags: gconf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I group/un-group parent/child windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5853/how-do-i-group-un-group-parent-child-windows)

I've lost track of which setting I tweaked in gconf-editor.

Now, my child windows/dialogs stay on-top of the parent.
... and oddly enough the VirtualBox main console window stays on top of the client window.

I usually keep a log of settings I tweak, but this time I didn't.

Does anyone know where this setting is?

** PS. oops.. I just realized I posted this question the other day.