# Clicking a window's decoration brings the window to the top, but clicking elswhere does not!

Tags: mouse, window-manager

To bring a window to the **"top"** via the mouse (ie. to bring it above other overlapping windows), I need to click on the **window decoration**.

Clicking anywhere else in the window, activates the window, but **does not** bring it to the top. Overlapping windows remain overlapped (obscuring the window I've just clicked on... until I click on the window decoration).
This mouse-click issue occurs with a maximized window too.

Keyboard actions like `<Alt>+Tab` work fine; the window comes fully into view.

This behaviour is the same for:
  * Compiz window manager (with the GTK window decorator)
  * Compiz window manager (with the Emerald window decorator)
  * Metacity window manager

Is there some magic button to press to bring things back to normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CompizConfig Settings, under General Options, check Raise on click.

If you don't have CompizConfig, install package `compizconfig-settings-manager`.

[image]

Comment: Well that was too easy... I've been looking for that pesky setting for weeks! ... Thanks so much.. :) ... but I don't quite understand how it still applied when Metacity was the manager.. maybe it was becasue this setting is passed on to the new manager.. (time passes) ... I just checked it in Metacity...yes "All systems are go!!" :)

Comment: To paraphrase von Neumann, "In gnome configuration you don't understand things. You just get used to them."

Comment: Awesome, thanks for putting this on here... I was looking for it to enable the very behavior the OP wanted to get rid of. :)  Via la linux!