# Is there a way to group 2 or 3 gui windows so that they don't get lost behind other open windows?

Tags: gnome, gui, window

For instance floating panels and main window in Gimp are independent windows. If I change focus to a full window (e.g. Firefox by doing Alt-Shift) and go back to the main Gimp window I don't get back the floating panels also (I have to change to them as well in order to see them). It would be great if the 3 windows can be "tied" (or linked) together in order that they don't get lost behind other open windows when I change back to (make active window) any of them? I think this configuration (if it exists) should show itself more obviously in the gnome environment.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5853/how-do-i-group-un-group-parent-child-windows)  seems to address the same problem but it doesn't seem to be accurately answered.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't seem to be accurately answered". What did you try and what happened when you did?

Comment: That answer refers to another Askubuntu answer saying: "In CompizConfig Settings, under General Options, check Raise on click." As I understand this option has no relationship to my question, anyway it was already checked on my system.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/805515/how-can-i-group-windows-to-be-raised-as-one, https://askubuntu.com/questions/681259/window-grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually window-manager dependent ([read more here](http://svenfoo.geekheim.de/2005/05/12/transient-docks/)), but the GIMP devs did try to workaround the problem by offering a "transient dock" method in the 2.5 series.  When 2.6 was released, the option was removed for some reason, but [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5895962&postcount=50) indicates that you can still activate the functionality if you need it.

The easiest workaround though seems to be "use compiz" (in other words, turn on Visual Effects in system-->preferences-->appearance.  I've tested it just now and with compiz, the docks magically restore themselves in line with the main window.  They also don't appear in the alt-tab list as an option you can use - only the main window.  Something to do with this option in Gimp-->Edit-->Preferences, Windows Management tab :

[image]

Comment: True. In the present edition of Gimp and Compiz (I'm in Natty) it is supported by default (seems to be a Gimp feature). In Compiz you need (if you don't have it already): CompizConfig Settings Manager > Window Management > Static Application Switcher > Bindings, then associate Alt-Tab and Shift-Alt-Tab to Next window and Prev window, respectively. You can even allow just the main window in a group to appear in the (popup) switcher: in the next tab Behaviour, in Switcher windows delete Utility.