# How to group different apps in one launcher in gnome?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, launcher

Is there a way to work witch different aplication windows like Libreofice & VS Code as if windows of one application.

My idea is that some application windows should be divided into logical groups - editors, viewer applications (Chrome, VLC), etc (not only windows of one app)

I want to use keyboard shortcut "Super + `" (Switch windows of an application) for switch apps in group. And  "Super + tab" for switch between groups.

Maybe need to launch apps from one app(via terminal) or simulate one app as if other?

Comment: Please [edit] this questioni to change `witch` to `with` and `aplication` to `application`.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/805515/how-can-i-group-windows-to-be-raised-as-one, https://askubuntu.com/questions/681259/window-grouping

Answer (score 0):

One way to work like this is to **use workspaces**. Open "grouped" applications on one workspace, a different group on the other. You can then switch between groups, aka workspaces by:

- Using the Overview
- Using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn/PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Dn</kbd>

You can even **assign shortcut keys** to quickly move to one desktop aka group. For example,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 "['<Super>F2']"
```

will allow you to quickly switch to Workspace 2 with <kbd>Super+F2</kbd>. Reset to default (no key assigned) with the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2
```

Rather than using commands, you can also assign these keys using `dconf-editor` (not installed by default).

You can use the "Auto move" gnome shell extension to have applications **automatically launch on a specific workspace**. "Auto move" is an "official" gnome shell extension, that you can install by installing the package `gnome-shell-extensions`. You need to activate the extension using "Gnome Tweaks" or the "Extensions" tool (newer Ubuntu versions only).

For this to work well, you better move from dynamic workspaces to **static workspaces**. You can change that in "Gnome Tweaks" on the "Workspaces" tab.